# socket io get saved property in client object

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a login event that saves a users id to the socket instance:

```
const io = socket(server);
io.on('connect', socket=>{
    socket.on('login', data=>{
        const user = jwt.verify(data.token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        socket.client.user_id = user._id;
    });
});

const friend = io.of('/friend');
friendSocket.loadFriendSocket(friend, io);
```

In another namespace, I have access to the global namespace socket:

```
loadFriendSocket: (friendIO, globalIO) =>{ 
    //...other code
    const clients = globalIO.sockets.sockets;
    const keys = Object.keys(clients);
    for(let i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
        const client = clients[keys[i]];
        console.log(client.client);
    }
}
```

However, there is no user_id property in the object. Is the property not being saved, or am I looking in the wrong place? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The socket ids in multiple namespaces not same, theres hashTag prefixes like ```namespace#sddfsdfsdf ``` or etc. i can't remeber well.

Comment: but shouldn't the user_id stay the same even if the ids get changed?

Comment: what is the value of ```friendSocket``` ?

Comment: `friendSocket` is an exported object from another module and `loadFriendSocket` is a function in the object.